# VSCode - Just-In-Time Debugger Error on Launch

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open VSCode this Just-In-Time debugger error pops up, what is this and how can I fix this on my system?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable or disable JIT(Just-In-Time) Debugger

Checkout this blog: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger?view=vs-2022

Comment: Thank You
, I also tried to uninstall Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 that was on my laptop, then re-installed the latest Visual Studio 2022, however the error persisted.

Then I followed your advice, and removed those registry keys mentioned in the article you posted. and now I no longer seem to have that issue.